# rc-tabs not working: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I used the rc-tabs library in Nextjs and got an error. But Reactjs does not. I don't understand why or the rendering mechanism.
Error: Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components)
github: https://github.com/HoTrHieu/Nextjs.git (http://localhost:3000/order)
This is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import Tabs, { TabPane } from 'rc-tabs';

const order = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Tabs defaultActiveKey="2" onChange={() => {}}>
        <TabPane tab="tab 1" key="1">
          first
        </TabPane>
        <TabPane tab="tab 2" key="2">
          second
        </TabPane>
        <TabPane tab="tab 3" key="3">
          third
        </TabPane>
      </Tabs>
    </div>
  );
};

export default order;
```

I tried other libraries like react-best-tabs, react-tabs. But still the same error

I took 2 screenshots of the error
[image]

[image]

[struct project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGlVC.png)

Comment: Looks like there is no error here. Can you share the parent component?

Comment: FWIW, [component names must begin with a captial letter](https://react.dev/learn/your-first-component#step-2-define-the-function).

Comment: @RohitSharma I have just add 2 picture 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmxY7.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrkQO.png

Comment: @devpolo
It is new project, parent component is _app.js
```
import '../styles/globals.css'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}

export default MyApp
```

Comment: @RohitSharma Order component is the page, http://localhost:3000/order
screenshot struct project: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGlVC.png

Comment: Can you add your `packages.json`?

Comment: @devpolo yes
{
  "name": "nextjs-v12",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "13.2.4",
    "rc-tabs": "^12.5.10",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "8.36.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.2.4"
  }
}

Comment: @devpolo http://localhost:3001/order, link git project: https://github.com/HoTrHieu/Nextjs.git

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used this lib before but it looks like `rc-tabs` have no export of `TabPane` (and they did not update the docs to reflect this change).

`Tabs` is not accepting `children` as well. You should use `items` props instead. Here is a simple working exemple to use it:

```js
import React from "react";
import Tabs from "rc-tabs";

const Order = () => {
  const tabs = new Array(8).fill(0).map((_, index) => {
    return {
      key: index.toString(),
      content: `tab content ${index + 1}`,
    };
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <Tabs
        defaultActiveKey='2'
        onChange={() => {}}
        items={tabs.map(({ key, content }) => ({
          key,
          label: `tab ${key}`,
          children: content,
        }))}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Order;
```

Comment: I saw your answer, this library comes from ant design, the librarian doesn't update the document, so it doesn't accept the syntax. Although the error has been fixed, it still seems to show the wrong interface => doesn't hide previous tabs, so i'm looking at the lack of css